# How would you calculate j in this function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

consider the function below which converts the result of a * b in a couple of numbers i and j, where:

1. a, b, x, y are int (Suppose they are always => 32bit-long)
2. a and b are <= n*m, where n = 10^3 and m=10^5. n*m = BASE.
3. a * b can be written as i*BASE + j

How would you calculate j **without using any types larger than int** (in case be careful about overflows with int's which are UB):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int n = 1000, m = 100000;

struct N {
        int i, j;
};

N f(int a, int b) {
        N x;
        int a0, a1, b0, b1, o;
        a1 = a / n;
        a0 = a - (a1 * n); // a0 = a % n
        b1 = b / m;
        b0 = b - (b1 * m);  // b0 = b % m
        o = a1 * b1 + (a0 * b1) / n + (b0 * a1) / m;
        x.i = o;
        x.j = 0; // CALCULATE J WITH INTs MATH
        return x;
}

int main(int, char* argv[]) {
        int a = atoi(argv[1]),
        b = atoi(argv[2]);
        N x = f(a, b);
        cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << x.i << "*" << n*m 
             << " + " << x.j << endl;
        cout << "which is: " << (long long)a * b << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? It's ok if it is - just good to let us know. :)

Comment: @taryn, looks more like an interview question

Comment: Why is BASE split into `n` and `m`? I see nothing in the question that specifies any constraint based on either variable.

Comment: @Suraj - I tend to always ask... just in case. But you're right, it does look like more an interview question.

Comment: You can use BASE = 10^8 if you prefer, but then you'll have to calculate i with integers in a portable way. n, m are actually used to split a and b

Comment: Can you give some sample input and sample output

Comment: Please don't use o as an identifier, it is too easily confused with 0.

Answer (score 2):

You started correctly, but lost the plot around calculation of `o`. First, my assumptions: you don't want to deal with any integer greater than `n*m`, so taking `mod n*m` is cheating. I am saying this, because given `m > 2^16`, I have to assume int is 32-bit long, which is capable of dealing with your numbers without overflowing.

In any case. You have correctly (I guess, since purpose of `n` and `m` are not specified) written:

```
a=a0 + a1*n (a0<n)
b=b0 + b1*m (b0<m)
```

So, if we do the math:

```
a*b = a0*b0 + a0*b1*m + a1*b0*n + a1*b1*n*m
```

Here, `a0*b0 < n*m`, so it is part of `j`, and `a1*b1*n*m > n*m`, so it is part of `i`. It is the other two terms that you need to split into two again. But you cannot calculate each and take the `mod n*m`, since that would be cheating (as per my rule above). If you write:

```
a0*b1 = a0b1_0 + a0b1_1*n
```

You get:

```
a0*b1*m = a0b1_0*m + a0b1_1*n*m
```

Since `a0b1_0 < n`, `a0b1_0*m < n*m`, which means this part goes to `j`. Obviously, `a0b1_1` goes to `i.`

Repeat a similar logic for a1*b0, and you've got three terms to add up for `j`, and three more to add up for `i`.

---

EDIT: Forgot to mention a  few things:

- You need the constraints `a < n^2` and `b < m^2` for this to work. Otherwise, you need more a<sub>i</sub> "words". e.g.: `a = a0 + a1*n + a2*n^2, ai < n`.
- The final sum of `j` may be greater than `n*m`. You need to watch for overflow ( `n*m - o  < addend`, or a similar logic, and add `1` to `i` when this happens - while calculating `j + addend - n*m` without overflow).

Comment: hmm i think this logic requires an algorithm.

Comment: Not really. The math for identifying components are there. Just add `a0*b0`, `a0b1_0` and `a1b0_0` carefully (watching out for overflows as I've suggested at the end of the answer), and you've got `j`.

Answer (score 1):

I think answer will be j = a0 * b0

```
(a*b)/(n*m) = (a/n) * (b/m)
            = (a1 + a0/n) * (b1 + b0/m)
            = a1*b1 + a1*b0/m + a0*b1/n + (a0*b0)/(n*m)
```

now

```
o = a1*b1 + a1*b0/m + a0*b1/n
```

multiply both side with n*m

```
a * b  = o * n*m  +  a0*b0
```

n*m is base

```
a * b  = o * BASE  +  a0*b0

j = a0*b0
```

QED

Comment: Hello CantGetANick, try to compile the program I had given which should obey to same math operations you told. Try to set x.j = a0*b0 in the code and then run it ./program 1234578 8754321  . Why is a0*b0  31397538 instead of 92111538 ? I miss something..

Comment: well..it's because of loosing precision during divisions.. the math is ok, but we are working with integers when calculating a0, b0

Comment: This answer is wrong because `o` is not necessarily an integer.  (Try your algorithm with n = 1, m = 7, a = 3, b = 3, for instance.)

Comment: Te problem is, a1*b0 is not necessarily divisible by m, and neither a0*b1 by n. j will have the parts from the remainders of these.

Comment: Yes, as Dysaster says, the problem is a1*b0 /m and a0*b1/n

Comment: Nemo is right o is not integer. The question is asked in a incorrect way.